# Meteor iron:router prepare request.body when JSON

Tags: json, meteor, request, iron-router

Currently I play around with iron:router's solution for a restful API. For this I use the `.put`, `.get` ... methods which are iron:router has implemented.

This is my example I work with:

```
Router.route('/api', {where:'server'})
.put(function(){

  var req;
  req = this.request;
  console.log(req.body);

  this.response.end('PUT finished.');

});
```

When I execute the following I will get the expected response (PUT finished):

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:4000/api " -d'{"name": "timo"}'
```

But the `console.log(req.body)` returns a strange value converted to an object.

The returned value is:

```
{ 
  '{"name": "timo"}\n' : '' 
}
```

It seems that iron:router trys to convert the body into an object but did not recognized that the given request string is a valid JSON string.

Is there smth I did wrong ? I did not find anything helpful yet to prepare iron:router that the given request body is still JSON.

Maybe its a better solution not to tell iron:router that the given request is a JSON and instead to tell iron:router that it shouldn't do anything so I can convert the JSON string by myself ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the content type in your curl request. Try this instead:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:4000/api " -d'{"name": "timo"}' -H "content-type: application/json"
```

With that it works for me:

```
I20150522-09:59:08.527(-7)? Request { name: 'timo' }
```

(and without it doesn't).

Comment: Alright - thanks for the hint. But it is possible also to be prepared that users do not request with the content-type given ? It just would be nice to work directly with the data as object and that it doesn't matter if the user send the request with content type or if not.